# continuous action on weakly compact

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

we know that each continuous function action on a compact subset of Banach space is uniformly continuous. now this is True for continuous action on weakly compact subset of Banach space?

Comment: I think it should not be difficult to construct a counterexample on something like $L^2$.

Comment: Well, when you say continuous do you now mean weakly continuous? Then you might have a shot. But if continuous means strongly continuous then no, you can build examples on $L^2$ with $f[\sin(n\pi x)]$ not converging to $f[0]$.

Comment: thanks, is the proof for weakly cotinuous is similar to strongly continuous?

Comment: Not really, because the weak topology is generally not metrizable.

Comment: then there is no proof for weakly continuous action on weakly compact?